# Lack of understanding while writing algorithm in Latex

Tags: overleaf, algorithms, latex3

I'm having trouble writing this algorithm in Latex (exactly as it is in the picture below). I was searching for the best solution, but can't seem to find something that I understand. Can someone help me? Much appreciated
[image]

Comment: For a simple method, but not very pretty, you could try the tabbing environment; see http://www.ctex.org/documents/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-58.html

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay thank you, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm writing a master thesis, so it needs to be fully formal.

Comment: you need a \kill line and then tabbing can produce exactly our desired output.